# Powershell: Throwing Exception in Catch block terminates but does not output Exception to console

Tags: powershell, exception, try-catch, powershell-4.0

I recently started having this weird issue where my Exception is caught in my catch block but when rethrowing it terminates the script (as expected) but does not write the re-thrown exception to console. I am not concerned about the specific exception that is being thrown, I only care that the exception is re-thrown and the stacktrace is output to console. I am using PowerShell 4.

```
try {
    $variable1 = 'value1'
    $variable2 = 'value2'
    [string[]]$variable3 = 'value3'

    [Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]]$matches = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]
    $matches = `
        Get-Matches `
            -Param1 $variable1 `
            -Param2 $variable2 `
            -Param3 $variable3 `
            -Silent $true

    Write-Host `n`nTotal Matches Found: $matches.Count
} catch {
    throw $_
}
```

I've also attempted the following alterations to the catch block:

```
} catch {
    throw
}
```

```
} catch {
    throw $_.Exception
}
```

```
} catch {
    throw $_.Exception.Message
}
```

```
} catch {
    throw $error[0].Exception
}
```

```
} catch {
    throw $error[0].Exception.Message
}
```

Comment: What is Get-Matches doing? Since it is some customer cmdlet/function you are using and we'd have no idea what to expect from it. Where's the code?

Comment: For one thing, **do not** use variable name `$matches` as self-defined variable, because it is an [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#matches) in PowerShell.

Comment: @postanote, Does it matter what Get-Matches is doing? I don’t care about what Exception is being thrown (which is a type conversion error), I care about the exception being thrown in the catch block according to Microsoft documentation. The exception is thrown after Get-Matches returns it’s result and fails when assigning that result to the variable $matches.

Comment: @Theo, thank you for that information. I don’t think that was the root of my issue but that is definitely useful information.

Answer (score 0):

To output the exception to the screen in your catch block, use the following:

```
try {
    #code
} catch {
    #handle exception
    Write-Output $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Additionally your `throw` should be within your try statement. No point throwing an exception within a `catch` block as one has already been thrown and caught to be there!

```
try {
    #code
    if($something -ne $right) {
        throw "Something isn't right!" 
    } 
} catch {
    #handle exception
    Write-Output $_.Exception.Message
}
```